# Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/semaphore_tracker.py'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

Currently I am working on jupyterlab on google cloud platform AI platform. Details of the Instance is here [instance details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3zeX.png)

When I run this :

```
  fin = open("/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/semaphore_tracker.py", "rt")
  data = fin.read()
  data = data.replace('if cache:', 'if False:')

  fin = open("/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/semaphore_tracker.py", "wt")
  fin.write(data)
  fin.close()
```

I got this error:

```
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_19868/1619868681.py in <module>
     22   fin.close()
     23 
---> 24   fin = open("/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/semaphore_tracker.py", "wt")
     25   fin.write(data)
     26   fin.close()

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/semaphore_tracker.py'
```

can anyone tell me how to get rid of that?

Comment: The files in "/usr/lib/" are usually not supposed to be overwritten. You have to be a superuser to change them, and even then it is a bad idea. Why are you trying to change that file?

Comment: By default a Notebook instance runs as jupyter user. You need sudo. I dont know why you are changing that file, but I recommend you to do it via SSH at your own risk.